# Append to widget style

Tags: dojo

if a style has already been specified on a widget, for example myWidget.style.witdh = "100%", now do I append more into the inline style later and tack on after this width for example?  Like I want to add display: inline-block or whatever else after the width: 100%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this can be done on a widget's `domNode` property using the standard dojo.style/domStyle.set methods.

for example:

```
require(['my/widget','dojo/dom-style'],function(Widget,domStyle){
  var widget = new Widget({},myNode);
  widget.startup();
  domStyle.set(widget.domNode,'display','inline-block');
});
```

The [dojo/dom-style](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dom-style.html) documentation has many reference cases for how you can use it.

Comment: would that add to the existing style?  Because for the dropdown sub widget style is set in that custom control itself to width: 100% but we want to be able to append other styles to it later on.

Comment: this should technically work I would think:            this.someSelect.style.display = "float: right";  here i'm referencing the attach point of the sub widget and setting its display value.

Comment: `dom-style#set` will either append a new style if one does not already exist, or replace the existing one if the same property is already specified.